# Moving textblock using StoryBoard - UWP c#

Tags: xaml, uwp, storyboard

I want to move a textblock from left to end of screen. I have done like below. It slides from right end to left. But for lengthy texts it is not showing all texts. How can I resolve this?

```
           <Grid>
                <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Background="Blue">
                <Canvas.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 2000, 800" />
                </Canvas.Clip>
            <TextBlock Name="txtScrollingNotification" Foreground="White" 
                   Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkklllllllllllllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooopppppppppppppppppppppppppp" Canvas.Top="6" />
            </Canvas>
      <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
                    <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="txtScrollingNotification"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                Duration="0:0:10" From="2000"
                To="0"  
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"  />
                </Storyboard>
            </Grid.Resources>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: What is the Canvas.Clip used for? Anything outside the Clip region is invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by setting From and To value of DoubleAnimation programmatically

```
 private void LoadScrollingTextBlock()
    {
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.From = this.ActualWidth;
        doubleAnimation.To = -txtScrollingNotification.ActualWidth;
        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(55)); // provide an appropriate  duration 
                                                                           //marquee.(Canvas.LeftProperty, doubleAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, txtScrollingNotification);
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "(Canvas.Left)");
        sb.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see all the text before the animation? It could be that your element isn't wide enough to display all the text.

If you add text wrapping to your text box, the text will wrap at the end of the element so you can see these dimensions

```
<TextBlock 
   Name="txtScrollingNotification" 
   Foreground="White" 
   Width="2000"
   TextWrapping="Wrap"
   Text="long text" 
   Canvas.Top="6" />
```

Comment: You have to give it a `Width` in order for the `TextWrapping` property to work.  The `TextBlock` has no bound (no Width) since it is in a Canvas.

Comment: The text box doesn't have a width, but the RectangleGeometry has a width of 2000 which is why I thought that the element might not be wide enough to display the text. I have updated my answer to include a width.

Comment: When Width increases can able to see some more texts. Is there any way to auto adjust this? because length of text may change dynamically